# Documentation for IDE's

Tags: javascript, ide

I'm using IntelliJ but this question could apply to PhpStorm, Visual Studio, etc...  Is there a good way to make the IDE aware of the Javascript functions that WordPress provides?  Are there any Javascript stubs available like these [Google Maps stubs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14529090/132374)?

I'd like to have auto-completion available, parameter info, etc...

Comment: Consider posting [a feature request](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/dashboard) at JetBrain's website. For v8.0 they added a bunch of WordPress functionality.

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution is to make the WordPress source code available to the IDE by adding it's path to the project.  IntelliJ reads the Javascript functions available.

This is not a pretty solution though (I'd like someone to be able to load the project on their machine and have this work).